# Wordpress save metabox checkboxes selection

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, meta-boxes

Having an issue whereby the checkboxes inside a metabox aren't saving. I can save one value and have it return the value of checked to the checkboxes, just not multiple values, which I need. I've tried adding a foreach loop to the update_post_meta code but it didn't work. Slightly confused as to where I'm going wrong.

checkbox code is:

```
$areas = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM locations ORDER BY locationName ASC");
                            if( count($areas) ) :
                                ?>

                                <div id="locationAssignedBoxes" size="1">
                                    <?php


                                    foreach($areas as $area) :
                                        ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="locationAssigned" name="locationAssigned" value="<?php echo $area->id; ?>"<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'locationAssigned', true) == $area->id) { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> />&nbsp;<?php echo $area->locationName; ?><br>
                                        <?php
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php
                            endif;
                            ?>
```

Update_post_meta code is:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'locationAssigned', $_POST['locationAssigned']);
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a cut-and-paste answer to your question, but it should help. (I'm trying to solve a similar problem.)

Your problem in general: **update_post_meta()** saves a single meta value, not a collection of values. Because you want to save the values of multiple checkboxes, you have two choices:

1. Call **update_post_meta()** once for each of the checkboxes, creating a
   collection of meta values associated with the post.
2. Combine all of the checkbox values into a single string and save those as a single value with one **update_post_meta()** call.

These two earlier questions are related and might point you in the right direction.

- [Save checkboxes of a metabox with a foreach loop (invalid argument)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145531/save-checkboxes-of-a-metabox-with-a-foreach-loop-invalid-argument)
- [Listing Pages With Checkboxes In a Metabox (and saving them)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71043/listing-pages-with-checkboxes-in-a-metabox-and-saving-them?rq=1)